# V-icon não está funcionando no vuetify

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify

Pessoal que utiliza o vuetify, o v-icon não está funcionando como deveria. Coloquei a imagem 1 ai que dá pra ver que não tá reconhecendo os ícones do material design.

Para entenderem melhor, eu criei um componente chamado **Aplication** e importei ele no meu "App.vue", daí eu utilizei o **Aplication** com um v-if pra verificar se o cara tá logado no sistema ou não. Se ele tá logado no sistema, ele mostra o **Aplication**, se não, não. E tá funcionando normal o v-if, ele mostra lá o sistema depois o usuário loga, normal. O problema é que os ícones estão dando problema como tá no print ali. E tô com receio também de outras coisas não funcionarem.

Alguem pode me ajudar? Alguem imagina o que possa estar dando esse erro?

Obs: a imagem 3 é apenas pra mostrar que eu importei de maneira certa o **Aplication** lá no components na parte do script.

[image: Imagem 1]

[image: imagem 2]

[image: imagem 3]

Answer (score 0):

Esse problema ocorria comigo quando a requisição para os icones que estavam hospedados em um site externo dava algum erro, a forma que que encontrei pra ajustar isso foi instalar os icones na pasta do projeto com:

```
npm install @mdi/font -D
ou
yarn add @mdi/font -D
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start